# Distributing 3d points by value across a honeycomb hex grid

Tags: algorithm, colors, grid, distribution, hexagonal-tiles

I'm looking for ways of interpolating a set of colors (3d values of r, g, b represented as [0-5] respectively)  across a hexagonal honeycomb grid.

My specific scenario is a set of terminal colors: 6x6x6 colors with white (5,5,5) being the center, making it a perfect fit for a [9 cell edge honeycomb grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5qd3.png) (217 cells)

The goal is to produce a grid/picker specifically for this set, similar to https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_gradient.asp

I'm pretty lost on what approach I could take, or if there are any established methods to distribute them interpolating the values.

Best I could do was to interpolate r, g, and b values towards the three opposing corners and then interpolate between the "branches", but I ended up filling duplicates. I believe there is a better way to do this?